# Loading Screen doesn't appear inside QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, loading, gif

I have created a Loading screen that is supposed to appear when I click a button that runs a specific script performed by the **run_script()** function in the code below and disappear when the execution of the script is complete and the **show_popup()** function is called. I have used for that the **QMovie**, unfortunately the Qwidget appears normally when the button is clicked and the function **run_script()** is called but the loading gif image doesn't appear inside the Widget, but it appears after the script is finished to execute. I have omited the the **stopAnimation()** for the sake of test in order to see if the Loading widget appears normally:

```
class LoadingScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.label_animation = QLabel(self)
        # self.label_animation.setStyleSheet("""{ background-image: url('./Icons/Pulse-1s-100px.gif');}""")
        self.movie= QMovie('./Icons/Pulse-1s-100px.gif')
        self.label_animation.setMovie(self.movie)
        # self.label_animation.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./Icons/Pulse-1s-100px.gif"))
        # timer= QTimer(self)
        # timer.singleShot(3000,self.stopAniamtion)
        self.show()


    def startAnimation(self):
        self.movie.start()


    # def stopAniamtion(self):
        # self.movie.stop()
        # self.close()

     def run_script(self):

        self.loading_screen= LoadingScreen()

        self.loading_screen.startAnimation()

     def show_popup(self, state):
        # self.loading_screen.stopAniamtion()
```

when I click the button the run_script() is called the widget appears but nothing inside. After the script finished the execution the loading gif appears inside the widget. What I think is that the function run_script() is faster than the loading of the gif inside the Widget.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: ok I'll do my best to provide u with that cuz I'am working on a little big project with a few hundreds of lines of code